# Is there a way to check if the file line being read is the last line in the file?

Tags: c

I want a way to check when the last line of the file is being read. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Not unless you count the number of lines first, and then keep track of the count while reading the lines. Or otherwise know the file position of the last line.

Comment: is there maximum line lenfth?

Comment: @tinky_winky No, but I strlen every line that is read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Attempt to read another line. If that yields an end-of-file condition, then the line you read before was the last line. There are kinda-sorta-maybe ways to get similar results without trying to read another line but they only work under specific conditions and are prone to race conditions.

If this is too complex, consider writing a wrapper around the function you use to read a line that buffers one line for you. This wrapper can then pretend to know that it reached the end of file easily by checking if it is able to read ahead another line.

Comment: I think the question intends to know if it can be done _without_ attempting another read. That could be beneficial for program logic, such as not having to start another loop iteration or needing special cases in the loop to handle EOF.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie It is possible, for example, you could wrap the IO logic to read one line in advance so it can tell you when it got to the last line. It is not possible in general to know in advance that you reached the last line without getting an EOF. You could check if you reached the end of file after reading a line which is exactly what my answer suggests to do.

Comment: If you downvoted my question, please explain why. A downvote without an explanation is not useful.

Comment: My downvote should be implicit from my comment: in my opinion you did not answer the question in a meaningful way. But I approach the question more from a theoretical point of view.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I'm sorry that "no you can't" is not an acceptable answer to you. I even said why other approaches fail. I don't see what my answer is missing.

Comment: @FUZxxl, "no you can't" is an acceptable answer to me; "yes, read another line" is not as it is the obvious possibility, hence not asked.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Have you read the fourth sentence of my answer, too? Because that's where I state that other approaches generally don't work.

Comment: @FUZxxl What function would be the best to read in a new line to get the EOF return? When i look at the man page for fgets I dont see a EOF reutrn.

Comment: @John `fgets` returns `NULL` on IO error or end-of-file. Use the `ferror()` function to check if an IO error occured. If no error occured, you can safely assume that `fgets()` encountered the end of the file it was reading from.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no general way to know if the line being read is the last line of the file.

The reason is that line number is determined exclusively by the data in your file. It is impossible to know on which line is your reader until you have read the relevant portion of the data, and checked it for presence of end-of-line markers.

Two special cases when you can tell the line number and even navigate to a specific line is when all lines in your file are as follows:

- **All lines have a pre-determined fixed length** - in this case a position in the file can be compared to the size of the file to decide if this is the last line or not
- **The file contains a "header" with indexes of all lines** - in this case you can perform additions, and determine positioning by analysis of your index.

Comment: other special case is lines have max length, not necessary fixed

Comment: @tinky_winky No, max length is insufficient. It is good enough to tell you that you are *not* on the last line (i.e. you are more than max length away from the end of the file) but it would not let you decide for certain that you have reached the last line of the file.

Comment: @tinky_winky Let's say max=1000. Imagine a file consisting of 1000 end-of-line characters. You are on the last line only when you reach position 999.

Comment: true, but it would be enough if check for single newline character was added

Comment: I upvote this answer because on unseekable devices the correct answer is "No, there is no general way". And you can leave "general" out.

Answer (score 1):

A way to tell if the line just read is the last line in the file...

```
FILE *fp = fopen( filename, "r" );
fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_END );
long filesize = ftell( fd );
fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

....

fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, fp);
if (filesize == ftell(fp) )
{
    // then last line is read
}
```

Naturally, appropriate error checking needs to be performed at each system function call; however, the above will let the code know when the last line is read.

Note: the above method will not work for pipes, fifos, and when accessing an external bus.

Comment: This is prone to a race condition when someone changes the file after you compute the file length.

Comment: @FUZxxl, wouldn't the permissions be normally set such that it will be opened exclusively? Differences here between Windows and Unix?

Comment: I Upvote this answer because it is an elegant way for files on seekable devices.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie POSIX only has advisory locks. Another process can steal your lock if it wants in which case you get a signal or something. It's really hard to get this right with an approach like this as you have to be extremely careful not to do something incorrect when you loose your lock. Much easier to process by not assuming anything about the file size unless you got the file.

Comment: @FUZxxl, OK, thx. Then you could repeat the `fseek` to end after each line. With all methods, including attempting another read, there can be race conditions such as the other process appending just after you did your last read..."darn..missed that on!"

Comment: @PaulOgilvie You couldn't because someone could truncate the file between the `fseek` check and the attempt to read another line. If you get an EOF while attempting to read another line, then the file ended there at that point of time and you can be 100% sure to have read the entire thing at that point of time.

Comment: @FUZxxl, can we then conclude that the only way, for seekable and unseekable devices, is to attempt another read?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Yes. Basically. If you can control everything else or if you are clairvoyant for some reason then the other approaches work, but usually that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

If file can be fseeked then it is possible to use fseek to do that if you know what is the maximum line length of this file.

```
ssize_t len;
char buf[max_len + 1];
//remember current position before fseek
currp = ftell(fd);

// set the file pointer to the beginning of the last line
fseek(fd, -max_len, SEEK_END);

// compare current position
if (ftell(fd) <= currp)
{
    // this might be the last line
    // now we have to check if there is only single '\n'

    // read file block
    len = read(fd, buf, max_len);
    if (len == -1)
    {
        perror("read failed");
        return -1;
    }
    buf[len] = '\0';
    if (strchr(buf, '\n') == strrchr(buf, '\n'))
    {
        // single newline was found
        // it is the last line
        // revert the pointer changes
        fseek(fd, currp, SEEK_SET);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

You must be aware of the possibility of the race conditions.

Comment: @FUZxxl I don't claim you can do this in a portable way